# Find duplicate strings in list and make them unique

Tags: java, list, duplicates, unique

I have an `ArrayList` with duplicate string values and want to make the duplicates unique by appending a count.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("a");
    list.add("b");
    list.add("c");
    list.add("d");
    list.add("b");
    list.add("c");
    list.add("a");
    list.add("a");
    list.add("a");

    HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
    List<String> duplicateList = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (String item : list) {
        // If String is not in set, add it to the list and the set.
        if (!set.contains(item)) {              
            set.add(item);
        } else {
            duplicateList.add(item);
        }
    }

    for (String element : duplicateList) {
        System.out.println(element);
    }
}
```

Is there any way to make the list like:

```
a
b
c
d
b1
c1
a1
a2
a3
```

Comment: Why are you storing the data in an array list? This is the point to start in the first place.

Comment: @ThomasJunk. I want the list with duplicate values. Is there anyway?

Answer (score 14):

Assuming that you use **Java 8**, if you want to get the total amount of duplicates of each value of your `List`, you could do that thanks to the [`Stream API`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) by grouping by values then counting occurences of each value as next:

```
Map<String, Long> counter = list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
System.out.println(counter);
```

**Output:**

```
{a=4, b=2, c=2, d=1}
```

---

If you want to prevent duplicates by adding a counter at the end of the original `String`, you can use [`LinkedHashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) to preserve the values' ordering as proposed by *Elliott Frisch*.

A slightly different approach from *Elliott Frisch*'s one:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "d", "b", "c", "a", "a", "a");
Set<String> set = new LinkedHashSet<>();
for (String str : list) {
    String value = str;
    // Iterate as long as you can't add the value indicating that we have
    // already the value in the set
    for (int i = 1; !set.add(value); i++) {
        value = str + i;
    }
}
System.out.println(set);
```

**Output:**

```
[a, b, c, d, b1, c1, a1, a2, a3]
```

Answer (score 11):

It seems like you have the right idea. You just need to use a `Map` and actually count the encountered strings instead of just noting that they were encountered:

```
Map<String, Integer> counter = new HashMap<>();
List<String> duplicateList = new ArrayList<>();

for (String item : list) {

    // If String is not in set, add it to the list and the set, and 
    // note this is the first time it's encountered
    if (!counter.containsKey(item)) {
        duplicateList.add(item);
        counter.put(item, 1);
    } else {
        Integer count = counter.get(item);
        duplicateList.add(item + count);
        item.put(item, count + 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You might use a [`LinkedHashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html), and you can use [`Arrays.asList(T...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-) to initialize your `List`. First, check if the set contains the element from the `list`. If it does, *iterate values* until you find one that does not already appear. Something like,

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "d", 
        "b", "c", "a", "a", "a"));
Set<String> mySet = new LinkedHashSet<>();
for (String str : list) {
    if (mySet.contains(str)) {
        int i = 1;
        while (mySet.contains(str + i)) {
            i++;
        }
        str = str + i;
    }
    mySet.add(str);
}
System.out.println(mySet);
```

Which outputs (as requested)

```
[a, b, c, d, b1, c1, a1, a2, a3]
```

Comment: @NicolasFilotto That `List` isn't mutable. Not certain if it matters in OP's case.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make changes to the existing List:

```
public static void main(String ... args) {
    List<String> names = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "d", 
            "b", "c", "a", "a", "a");

    updateDuplicates(names);

    System.out.println(names);

}

private static void updateDuplicates(List<String> names) {
    ListIterator<String> litr = names.listIterator();
    Map<String, Integer> occurenceCounter = new HashMap<>();
    while(litr.hasNext()) {
        String currentName = litr.next();
        if(!occurenceCounter.containsKey(currentName)) {
            occurenceCounter.put(currentName,0);
        }else {
            Integer currentCount = occurenceCounter.get(currentName);
            occurenceCounter.put(currentName, ++currentCount);
            litr.set(currentName + currentCount);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Java with Hashing *O(n)*

Here `l` is input List

```
public static List getUniqueList(List<String> l){
    HashMap<String,Integer> hm=new HashMap<String,Integer>();
    for(int i=0;i<l.size();i++) {
        String key=l.get(i);
        if(hm.containsKey(key)) {
            l.set(i, key+hm.get(key));
            hm.put(key,hm.get(key)+1);
        }else { 
            //newl.add(key);
            hm.put(key,1);
        }
    }
return l;
}
```